# SSO in Camunda using only Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, single-sign-on, camunda

I am trying to implement basic SSO for webapp applications and I want to use only basic authentication from Tomcat (basic http authentication and users' data from tomcat-users.xml).

Is it possible to create my own session for all 3 webapp camunda applications using this method?
Has somebody tried something similar?

So far, I have only experimented with Camunda filters, Tomcat permissions and recompiling existing Camunda classes.

Comment: I have used this project:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/deployment/embedded-spring-rest
and it's a very easy way to deploy Camunda Engine in Spring 3 webapp with Spring 3 security :)

Is there a way or example to deploy Camunda Engine in Spring 4?
Thanks in advance.